# Accessing GET Form data from - Javascript Form in Django

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm having trouble with Django in terms of getting data from a Javascript form. Here is my Javascript code...

```
    function save() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    console.log(form);
    form.setAttribute('method', 'get');
    form.setAttribute('action', '/quiz_score/');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute('name', 'Score');
    i.setAttribute('value', ""+score);
    form.appendChild(i);
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute('name', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken');
    i.setAttribute('value', '{{ csrf_token }}');
    form.appendChild(i);
    form.submit();
}
```

I know using GET isn't ideal however I couldn't get POST working, it simply wouldn't redirect to the target page.

Here is my Django Class and function...

```
class QuizScoreView(TemplateView):
template_name = "quiz_score.html"


def quiz_score(self, request):
    # Quiz.objects.create(username= ,score= )
    print("Score: "+request.body)
```

I am simply trying to get the score variable so I can use it in python.

Please comment if you need any more details and I will add them to the question below.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. What is the `quiz_score` method for? What is calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using the following HTML/JavaScript:

```
<html><body>
<button onclick="save();">click me</button>
<script>
function save() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    console.log(form);
    form.setAttribute('method', 'get');
    form.setAttribute('action', '/quiz_score/');
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute('name', 'Score');
    i.setAttribute('value', "+score");
    form.appendChild(i);
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    i.setAttribute('name', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken');
    i.setAttribute('value', '{{ csrf_token }}');
    form.appendChild(i);
    form.submit();
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def quiz_score(request):
    context = {'score': request.GET['Score']}
    return render(request, 'quiz_score.html', context=context)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^quiz_score/$', quiz_score)
```

I noticed in your JavaScript you have `i.setAttribute('value', ""+score);`.  Maybe that's supposed to be `i.setAttribute('value', "+score");` or something similar?

I went with a straight function view.  You have a interesting mix of TemplateView and function based view.  If you wanted to use a TemplateView, you could do something like:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class QuizScoreView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'quiz_score.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Score'] = request.GET['Score']
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^quiz_score/$', QuizScoreView.as_view())
```

Hope that helps!